# Переход с мобильной версии сайта на полную

Tags: javascript, html

Я сделал домен m.site.ru для мобильных устройств и на основную страницу добавил код, что если заходят с мобильного устройства, то переводит на мобильную версию сайта. Но вот допустим пользователю нужна полная версия, как ее реализовать? Код JS прилагаю, тогда ведь по возвращению на полную версию все равно на мобильную кидать будет.

```js
var isMobile = {
  Android: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
  },
  BlackBerry: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
  },
  iOS: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPod/i);
  },
  Opera: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
  },
  Windows: function() {
    return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
  },
  any: function() {
    return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
  }
};
if(isMobile.any()){
   document.location.href = 'http://m.site.ru/';
   } else if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Tablet|iPad/i)){
   //Что-то еще добавится 
   }
```

Comment: Вообще переход на мобильную версию нужно в PHP делать. А когда пользователь нажимает на полную версию, вы записываете куку, в которой прописываете, что нужно открывать компьютерную версию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сейчас уже не популярны мобильные версий. Правильно создать сайт с адаптивным дизайном, но то, что вы хотите, можно получить так:

```
if(isMobile.any() && !localStorage.getItem('webVer')){
   document.location.href = 'http://m.site.ru/';
   } else if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Tablet|iPad/i)){
   //Что-то ещё добавится 
   }
   function itsNotTablet() {
      document.location.href = "http://YOUR_URL/#webVer=true"
   };
   if(window.location.hash.split("=")[1]) {
      localStorage.setItem('webVer', true);
   }
```

При переходе с мобильны версий в адресе ставишь параметр, потом после перехода парсишь параметр и вставляешь в localstorage.